# In What Order UITableView sections are displayed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am getting data from a `sqlite3` database and i'm saving those things in an array and i'm using that array in `viewForHeaderInSection` method, every time my data will be different i mean section list will be different every time it is displaying randomly i need to display it in an order.
1. How a `UITableView` displays its sections(any sorting algorithm is there) or randomly it will display?
2. How can i sort my sections in an order?

Any help is thankful in advance.

Comment: This is probably due to your SQLite request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table view displays its sections in the order you tell it to. If you are populating an array for the sections from a SQL query, you can apply ordering in the query. If this is not possible, you can sort the array after population using one of the many sorting methods available on NSArray, for example `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`. See here for more:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit unclear. Better if you can post some code. You get different data from sqlite each time into array and that data is shown in sections. So why do you need to sort sections ? Instead, sort the array according to requirement and show the sorted data in section.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about the order of the sections or the order of the content within the sections?  For example:

Section 1
Section 3
Section 2

OR

Section 1
Row 1
Row 3
Row 2

Only the order of the Rows is determined by the order of the datasource of the uitableview.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are getting different unordered data form sqlite database into array.you want sort the array(arrList)data

```
arrList = [arrList sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSLog(@"%@",arrList);
```